# Query with IN operator not performing well in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, in-operator

I have a query in SQL Server something like this.

```
select sum (col1) 
from TableA 
where col2 = ? 
  and col3 = ? 
  and col4 = in (?, ?, ?... ?)
```

TableA has a composite index on (`col2, col3, col4`).

This query is not performing well when the size is increasing in the list of the `IN` operator.

Is there a good way to rewrite this query for better performance?

List can grow from 1 to 300 items.

Comment: You could put that value for the `in` clause in a table and join against it.

Comment: check the query plan and see index is working or not

Comment: @KedarLimaye index is working

Comment: @juergend Can you give an example for it. Are u proposing some sort of temp table to be created each time i need to run query or a table already there in DB and insert in it having index on the column and after joining clear that table back.

Comment: That might be that because when you're extending the list of values to be returned, you actually HAVE to return more rows, which turns your `Index Scan` or `Index Seek` into a possibly, a `Table Scan`. Without having an execution plan, more details about the index or cardinality of the table, we can't give you a precise answer.

Comment: The `In` operator has a bad reputation for chocking on large lists, but 300 isn't large enough, and also this behavior was improved in version 2008 (or 2012, not really sure). Try to change the index to include `col1` (as an included column) and see if the performance improves.

Answer (score 0):

Your index should be pretty good.  For this query:

```
select sum(col1) 
from TableA 
where col2 = ? and
      col3 = ? and
      col4 in (?, ?, ?... ?);
```

The optimal index is `(col2, col3, col4, col1)` (the last column can be included if you prefer.

For the index to be used, you need to be sure that the types are compatible for the comparisons.  Conversions -- and changes in collation -- preclude the use of indexes.